# ElasticSearch _suggest not returning results

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index that I'd like to get suggestions on:

```
{
    "book": {
        "_index": {
            "enabled": true
        },
        "_id": {
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "store": "yes"
        },
        "properties": {
            "author": {
                "type": "completion"
            },
            "characters": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "copies": {
                "type": "long",
                "ignore_malformed": false
            },
            "otitle": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "tags": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "title": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "year": {
                "type": "long",
                "ignore_malformed": false,
                "index": "analyzed"
            },
            "available": {
                "type": "boolean"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've loaded some data into it using _bulk endpoint.

When I try to query against the suggest endpoint:

```
POST library/book/_suggest
{
  "my_suggestion_1":{
    "text": "He",
    "term":{
      "analyzer":"standard",
     "field":"author" 
    }
  }
}
```

I get back this:

```
{
   "_index": "library",
   "_type": "book",
   "_id": "_suggest",
   "_version": 8,
   "created": false
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: BTW, I'm using Marvel Sense to execute the query, not CURL.

Comment: Also, I've tried using a non analyzed field in the mapping, to no avail.      "author" : {
         "type": "completion",
         "index": "not_analyzed"
      } ...

Comment: Are you sure you are sending your request body correctly in your `POST` request? The response you received is exactly what you'd receive if you sent `POST library/book/_suggest` without any request body. Also, consider reformatting the code in your question to make it legible.

Comment: @Shawn - you're right. The response returned is what I'd get back for an empty _suggest post request. However I haven't been able to figure out what's wrong with the POST request. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to use `completion` instead of `term` in your request body when you ask for suggestions:

```
POST library/book/_suggest
{
  "my_suggestion_1":{
    "text": "He",
    "completion":{
      "analyzer":"standard",
     "field":"author" 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In addition to the completion keyword, I also needed to use the following while defining the mappings for the field which would provide the suggestions: `"type":"completion", "index_analyzer": "simple",               "search_analyzer": "simple", "payloads": false`